# Difference between $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|\bar{X} - \mu| \geq \epsilon) = 0$ and $P(\lim_{n\rightarrow 1} \bar{X} = \mu) = 1$

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

These two expressions correspond to the weak and strong law of large numbers, respectively:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|\bar{X} - \mu| \geq \epsilon) = 0 \ \ \text{for } \epsilon > 0
\\
P(\lim_{n\rightarrow 1} \bar{X} = \mu) = 1
$$

I've always struggled to understand the difference between the two. It seems very subtle to me.
The first one is a limit over the probability, where as the second one the limit is within the probability and it's a limit over $\bar{X}$, the sample mean for $n$ samples.

But I cannot wrap my head around how these two are saying slightly different things.

The first one is telling me that when the number of samples approach infinity, the probability
that the sample mean is different from the population mean is zero.

The second one is telling me that the probability of the sample mean equating to the population mean is 1 when the number of samples approach infinity.

How are these two actually different? It reads to me pretty much the same.

Comment: The weak law describes convergence "in probability".  The strong law describes convergence "almost surely".    You may use those terms to search for this topic.  Specifically, there are many sequences of random variables that converge in probability but they don't converge almost surely to anything.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I will try searching those specific phrases. There are multiple posts about SLLN vs. WLLN, but I still couldn't comprehend the difference after reading those. When people (in the typical case) say "the sample mean approaches the population mean" as the number of samples increases, which LLN are they referring to? I've always thought it was SLLN. Some people also just say "the LLN implies the sample mean approaches the population mean as n->infinity" and doesn't say whether they're referring to the strong or weak versions.

Comment: Normally, we're talking about the strong law.  The weak law allows for the sample mean to "jump" away from the population mean infinitely often as long as the "big" jumps become more spread out as you count more in the sample.  I don't usually hear people talk about this type of convergence in the general population.